# Trying to call a function every 24 hours

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a function to be called every day.  Right now my code is as follows:

```
do {
    Thread.sleep(1000*60*60*24);
    readInFile();
} while (true);
```

The issue is that it is being called every day plus the time it takes to execute the function `readInFile`.  Is there a way to do a callback or something to go off every 24 hours?

Comment: Schedule an application to execute periodically using the host task scheduling system.  (Such as `cron` or Windows Task Scheduler for example.)  Sleeping a thread for 24 hours is generally a bad idea.

Comment: You could calculate the time it next needs to run. Then sleep for something like a minute and compare the current time with the calculated time.

Comment: If it has to be pure Java, I would look into Executors.newScheduledThreadPool.  Create your pool with a size of one and give it a Runnable that runs your readInFile() method.

Comment: You could also use another thread to execute the function, keeping this one active.

Comment: Or creep up on it by sleeping for 12 hours, 6, 3 and so on down to a second,say, recalculating the ms of sleep time remaining using the real-time clock.

Comment: why dont u try quartz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();
TimerTask t = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // some code
    }
};

timer.schedule (t, 0l, 1000*60*60*24);
```

or else you can use the  [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

> An ExecutorService that can schedule commands to run after a given
>   delay, or to execute periodically.

Comment: That is not going to be any better than sleep calls.

Comment: `s/schedule/scheduleAtFixedRate/`

Comment: @MartinJames:- Hmm..ScheduledExecutorService will do the trick. Tunaki has hit it.

Comment: `Timer`/`TimerTask` can do the right thing too but you need to use one of the  "AtFixedRate" versions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-long-long- what you do is "for repeated fixed-delay execution" which has the same problem as a fixed sleep.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method to invoke a `Runnable` at a fixed rate.

Sample code to invoke a runnable every day (with no initial delay):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a scheduler such as Quartz or Spring to set the code to be run once per day.

**Spring**
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

http://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

```
//1:01 am every day
@Scheduled(cron = "0 1 1 * * ?")
public void readDaily() {
  readInFile();
}
```

**Quartz**
https://quartz-scheduler.org

```
JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
    job.setName("dummyJobName");
    job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);

    //configure the scheduler time
    Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger("trigger1", "group1");
    trigger.setCronExpression("0 0 15 * * ?"); //3pm every day

    //schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```