# Running a method every day at a specific time with Timer()

Tags: java, kotlin, bukkit, timertask

Using Kotlin, Bukkit (Spigot), and Timer() (Or anything that also helps), I'm trying to create a way that I can run another method, every day at a specific time.

Here's what I have so far, which doesn't work.

```
fun schedule() {
        val timer = Timer()
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss") 
        val date = format.parse("11:07:09")
        timer.schedule(sendMessage(), format, date)
}

fun sendMessage() {
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

Doesn't work because `timer.schedule()` requires a `TimerTask`, `Date`, and a `long`.

What I'm confused about, how do I convert format and date so add it to `timer.schedule()` so this does run every day? Also, how would I respect timezones, and make sure this runs at-least near the server time?

Comment: Take a look this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375882/how-i-can-run-my-timertask-everyday-2-pm

Comment: @TimurLevadny Yeah I saw this question, and I tried to convert it to what I was doing, but with it not having the exact format I need (hh:mm:ss, which will be grabbed from a file) and the formatted date (11:07:09), it's confusing to use.

Comment: A nice practice to consider is to define an AWS lambda function as a timer that will trigger an endpoint you provide (if AWS lambda is available to you...)

Comment: @LiorBar-On not sure how do anything you said there.

Comment: Okay. Maybe you better create a new, more specific questions, about date conversion. It will be easier to answer than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val timer = Timer()
val task: TimerTask = object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
       // do your task here
    }
}
// repeat every hour
timer.schedule(task, 0L, 1000 * 60 * 60)
```

As refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105701/trying-to-call-a-function-every-24-hours).